# Different answers for `GCD` of 2 polynomials. Wolfram answer differs from answer obtained from my program of Euclids algorithm.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

The `GCD` of two polynomials

$f_1= (x^6 - 1)$,

$f2= (x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 − 2x − 3)$.

as per Wolfram alpha is $(x^2-1)$. But as per my Euclidean algorithm program the `GCD` is $(57/4)x^2 - (57/4)$.

The answer I got divides both the polynomials exactly and is greater than the answer of Wolfram alpha. So, which answer is the correct `GCD`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the greatest common divisor isn't actually unique--it's only unique *up to multiplication by a unit*.

So in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, both of those are the greatest common divisors, because you can multiply either by an invertible element to get the other one.

Now, on the other hand, sometimes people specify that the greatest common divisor be monic. That depends on how you've defined it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Actually, I don't know much finite algebra. I'm using polynomials to model circuits. So, I want to know how many GCDs are possible? Is it infinite or only 2?

Comment: Depends on the field your polynomials take coefficients from. If your field has two elements, it has one possible greatest common divisor. If your field has 17 elements, there are 16 possible GCD's (multiply your monic polynomial by anything but zero, that's also a greatest common divisor). If your field has infinitely many elements (like $\mathbb{Q}$) you have infinitely many different candidates for GCDs if you don't specify they be monic.